# Objeto no localizado Error 404 Laravel ResetPassword

Tags: laravel, xampp

Buenas espero que puedan ayudarme, tengo el siguiente error cuándo voy al link que me envia el mail de laravel.

he probado poniendo el '.com' al final de la URL tampoco funciona, he borrado cache y reiniciado el servidor...cada ves que hago alguno de estos cambios tengo que volver a enviar el mail? solo lo he hecho en algunos casos.

Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo tuve ese mismo problema porque accedía a mi proyecto por el puerto 8000 (el que pone por defecto al ejecutar `php artisan serve`, sin embargo el link me dirigía a localhost en lugar de localhost:8000, puede que sea eso

Comment: Y como lo solucionaste? He probado poniendo en la APP_URL=http://localhost:8000 pero no funciona, cada ves que hago cambios ejecuto php aritsan cache:clear no se si deberia usar alguna otra comanda.

Comment: Configura un Vhost, esto te ayudara en todos los proyectos que realices, basicamente lo que haces es simular una URL con un dominio, normalmente se usan URLs como "proyecto.test" hay muchos tutos en Youtube no es muy dificil ;)

Comment: @smiranda simplemente, cambié el `localhost` de la URL que manda al mail por la dirección que realmente utilizaba, no sé caul estás usando tú. Yo siempre he utilizado el comando `php artisan config:cache`, aunque no creo que tenga nada que ver

Comment: Vale si edito el puerto del archivo /bootstrap/cache/config.php si funciona, pongo el codigo en una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno edité el archivo `/bootstrap/cache/config.php` , en la url indiqué el puerto y si me redirigió correctamente a la ruta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]